# Did .NET 4 change how the Certificate Request frame is answered in TLS

Tags: .net, ssl, .net-4.0

I am connecting to a web service that is hosted in Win2008 (IIS7) requiring certificate based mutual authentication.  When the service is called by a client running on the .NET 2.0 runtime, the operation fails with a 403.  If I examine the request in wireshark I see that the client is responding to the **Certificate Request** frame with a **Certificate** frame but no certificate is specified in that frame.  Looking at the list of CA certificates provided by the server in **Certificate Request** the CA used by the client's certificate is not present.  This seem to make sense as what is the point of sending a cert if the service will not trust it.  However, when I make this same call using the tool recompiled against the .NET 4.0 runtime the behavior is different.  The client's **Certificate** frame does contain the certificate it was configured to use.  I saw on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#networking) that changes were made to SslStream so is this what I am running into? It is rather unsettling that different runtime versions act differently for the same service endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the behavior did change between the two versions of the runtime.  The nuanced change was in how the client processed the Certificate Request frame.  The issue that we experienced was that the server had too many CAs in its trusted root store due to [a bad root certificate update](http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2013/01/12/fix-available-for-root-certificate-update-issue-on-windows-server.aspx) issue.  This caused a subset of trusted CAs to be returned in the certificates array of the Certificate Request Frame.  As the list of returns CAs was a proper subset, it included the root that signed the client certificate in some requests and not in others.  The .NET 2.0 client properly honored the TLS spec by not including a certificate which was outside of the set of trusted authorities provided by the server.  The .NET 4.0 client honored how it was configured and provided the client certificate that was specified via the WCF configuration.